# 400 Bad Request with Adonisjs websocket

Tags: javascript, react-native, websocket, adonis.js

I'm runing a localhost adonisjs project with a websocket. I followed the adonis get started [here](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/websocket-server#sponsor). Everything in the server looks ok, but when I tried to connect in my react-native application a got this error:

```
{
  "isTrusted": false,
  "message": "Expected HTTP 101 response but was '400 Bad Request'",
}
```

This is my cliente code:

```
const ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.0.11:3333")

ws.onopen = () => {
    ws.send(JSON.stringify({
        t: 1,
        d: { topic: 'prelista:5999c0ea-6bbb-4e0f-9496-f62658bbac5' }
    }))
}

ws.onmessage = (e) => {
    console.log(e)
}

ws.onerror = (event) => {
    console.log(event)
}
```

This is my server code:

```
'use strict'

const Ws = use('Ws')

Ws.channel('prelista:*', ({ socket }) => {
  console.log(socket.topic)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my mistake. Whe we use Adonis websocket on the server side, we need to add `/adonis-ws` in the end of ws path. Well, changed this `const ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.0.11:3333")`
 to this `const ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.0.11:3333/adonis-ws")`

worked now